# pcre2 - Regex match to distinct letters only

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that matches the following criteria below

- first letter is uppercase
- remaining 5 letters following the first letter are lowercase
- ends in ".com"
- no letter repeats only before the ".com"
- no digits
- there are only 5 lowercase letters before the .com, with only the first letter being uppercase

The above criteria should match to strings such as:
Amipsa.com
Ipsamo.com

I created this regex below, but the regex seem to capture repeating letters - examples here: https://regex101.com/r/wwJBmc/1

```
^([A-Z])(?![a-z]*\1)(?:([a-z])\1(?!\2)(?:([a-z])(?![a-z]*\3)){3}|(?:([a-z])(?![a-z]*\4)){5})\.com$
```

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: Can you explain what *no letter repeats only before the ".com"* means?

Comment: How can there be "only 6 lowercase letters before the .com" if "first letter is uppercase" and "remaining 5 letters following the first letter are lowercase"?

Comment: I'm using a retool that uses pcre. 
"no letter repeats only before the .com" means, only letters before ".com" should be distinct. for example, if the website is Almnop.com, the regex should still match even though there are two "o"s in the string.

Comment: sorry, just updated that @ScottHunter

Comment: What tool or language are you using, specifically?

Comment: using regex in node. but we don't have the ability to use the ?i modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
^(?i)[a-z]*?([a-z])[a-z]*?\1(?-i)(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Z][a-z]{5}\.com$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/09vasj/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?i)` Case insensitive match
- `[a-z]*?([a-z])[a-z]*?\1` Match 2 of the same chars a-z A-Z
- `(?-i)` Turn of case insenstive
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `[A-Z][a-z]{5}` Match A-Z and 5 chars a-z
- `\.com` Match `.com`
- `$` End of string

---

Another idea if you are using Javascript and you can not use `(?i)` is to use 2 patterns, 1 for checking not a repeated character with a case insensitive flag `/i` and 1 for the full match.

```js
const rFullMatch = /^[A-Z][a-z]{5}\.com$/;
const rRepeatedChar = /^[a-z]*([a-z])[a-z]*\1/i;
[
  "Regxas.com",
  "Ipsamo.com",
  "Plpaso.com",
  "Amipsa.com",
  "Ipsama.com",
  "Ipsima.com",
  "IPszma.com",
  "Ipsamo&.com",
  "abcdef.com"
].forEach(s => {
  if (!rRepeatedChar.test(s) && rFullMatch.test(s)) {
    console.log(`Match: ${s}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in PCRE with a negative lookahead:

```sh
^(?!(?i)[a-z]*([a-z])[a-z]*\1)[A-Z][a-z]{5}\.com$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wwJBmc/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!`: Start negative lookahead

  - `(?i)`: Enable ignore case modifier
  - `[a-z]*`: Match 0 or more letters
  - `([a-z])`: Match a letter and capture in group #1
  - `[a-z]*`: Match 0 or more letters
  - `\1`: Match same letter as in capture group #1
- `)`: End negative lookahead
- `[A-Z][a-z]{5}`: Match 5 lowercase letters
- `\.com`: Match `.com`
- `$`: End

Comment: Honestly...this should be it ++

Comment: thank you! is there a way to create this regex without the negative lookahead (?!) and case modifier (?i) ? just seeing now that we're using an older version of regex that doesn't support these functions.

Comment: @Alex: You mentioned PCRE and that's the reason of these features in regex solutions. Checking repeat characters does require lookahead to be used and there is other regex feature that can replace this.